# Heading inside Alert dialog

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, android-alertdialog

I have created an [alert dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UpP53.jpg). The dialog displays options to switch to any of the hundred question. What I want to do is to give separate headings inside the dialog. For example, for first ten questions, I must give the heading as Round 1 and for next 10, it must be Round 2. How can that be done?

Comment: you can create custom layout and then apply it to your `Dialog`

Comment: Can you please explain more about that?

Comment: google for `android custom dialog`

Answer (score 0):

Creating custom Layout is best option here..

You can apply your layout to your `AlertDialog`.

-> First of all you have to create XML file for your content in the dialog.

-> Now in your Java file inflat your XML file and initialize `AlertDialog`

```
LayoutInflater inflat = LayoutInflater.from(this);
final View view = inflat.inflate(R.layout.custom_dialogbox, null);

AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Classname.this);
final AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
```

-> You can perform clickEvent of any Event on the view of your XMl file. for example if you have `Button` in your XML file.

```
Button ok = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.yesOk);
ok.setText("Ok");
ok.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        alert.dismiss();
        //Do somthong
    }
});
```

-> Now finally Add Your View to your `AlertDialog`.

```
alert.setView(view);
alert.show();
```

-> Done

I Hope this will help you.